# Should I remove the solder mask from an isolation-barrier?

Tags: pcb-design, isolation, digital-isolator

To be able to fully utilize the isolation properties of digital isolator ICs such as the [ISO7731](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/iso7731.pdf?ts=1600953559668&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F), the PCB must have an isolation barrier that is accoding to datasheets *Free from planes, traces, pads, and vias*.

How wide this barrier has to be typically depends on the IC package.  I typically use the width of two adjacent legs.

They do not however mention if solder mask should be kept on/off the barrier. I would assume the safest answer is to not place solder mask, but I do not know how insignificant/great the difference of having it on/off is. For example if the PCB is placed in a location where it could be seen in plain sight, and having no solder mask (especially on a colored solder mask) would not be aesthetically appealing.

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot mill a slot under the chip that gives the necessary clearance? I've used that a few times without any of the aesthetic concerns you mention.

Comment: @nanofarad its not the clearance that is actually the problem, its how not appealing to look at bare FR-4 looks to for example a black solder masked board.

Comment: Do you trust the solder mask to be insulating? If yes, you can place it there. Our devices have solder masks under isolator ICs / transformers, but our voltage levels are low (<35 V), so there could be other requirements than in your case.

Comment: What voltage levels?  Unless you are talking kilovolts, my understanding is most soldermasks should be fine (at reasonable temperatures anyway).

Comment: "Do you trust the solder mask to be insulating?" I know to little to even guess. On one of my project the highest voltage level is only 3.3v assuming ESD strikes are being handled by the TVS diode which are far from the isolation barrier with the closest one to 1cm from the barrier. Another however deals with 240 mains voltage but are directly divided down (by resistor voltage divider) to 1v right on the connector with the closest 4cm to the barrier. May i know what you think about this.

Comment: @evildemonic i missed your comment, i just talked about the voltage level on the comment above

Comment: @Jakequin The point I was trying to make is that a milled isolation slot means you don't need to worry about your solder mask, whether it might be hygroscopic, leaky, etc, and the slot looks pretty nice when done properly without even needing to consider whether you need ugly bare FR4.

Comment: @nanofarad point taken. I am still curious though about the question for the sake of knowing. I cannot just simply mill the entire barrier as it span all across the board and i just effectivly increase the distance  if  i mill specific sections

Comment: Effectively increasing the distance *is* the goal of milling short sections. I had rules that were suitable for masked boards, and I couldn't reach them without increasing distance via milling.

Comment: @Jakequin Open up a Kiethley coulomb meter and you'll see multiple cutaways, that nanofarad is talking about, on their boards.

Answer (score 6):

### TL;DR

As far as I know, there's almost no regulatory requirement to remove solder mask.

To be precise:

1. If the working voltage is below 630 Vrms, no regulatory requirement exists (I'm open to correction, but I cannot find any).
2. Above 630 Vrms, *and* under Pollution Degree 3 (conductive dust), there's an argument for removing solder mask.
3. Still, most electronics for home, office, and lab uses are designed for Pollution Degree 2 (non-conductive dust), not Pollution Degree 3, thus, no regulatory requirement exists for most designs at any voltage.

### Explanation

From experience, many circuit boards remove the solder mask across an insulation barrier in an attempt to increase its safety. Presumably, the reasoning is the following: the circuit board substrate, FR-4, is a material provided by its manufacturers with controlled electrical properties, on the other hand, a generic type of solder mask's electrical properties are poorly controlled. Thus, it's possible that solder mask has worse insulation than a bare circuit board.

But so far I didn't find any regulatory requirements to do so, at least under 630 V.

If the circuit board is designed according to a relevant regulatory standard [1], a generic FR-4 circuit board material has a Comparative Tracking Index of at least 175, and belongs to Material Group IIIa. A generic solder mask material, due to its unknown properties, is classified as Material Group IIIb by default. Then, one proceeds from here to calculate the required clearance and creepage distances. Both Material Group IIIa and IIIb are classified as the worst kinds of insulators, and have identical clearance and creepage requirements.

Thus, solder mask removal can be a good design practice, but it only has a small benefit with diminishing return, and it's not required by the regulation (which already accounts for the poor materials used and requires a large spacing).

Nevertheless, there's a fine-print in the standards on a small difference between Material Group IIIa/IIIb.

> Material Group IIIb is not recommended for applications in Pollution Degree 3 with an RMS working voltage above 630 V.

Thus, an argument can be made to remove solder mask for this application, since a circuit board is guaranteed to be Material Group IIIa, but the unknown solder mask can be Material Group IIIb, which the standards warn against. Still, most electronics for home, office, and lab uses are designed for Pollution Degree 2 (non-conductive dust), not Pollution Degree 3, thus, no regulatory requirement exists for most designs at any voltage.

Finally, there are always exceptions. Some circuit boards may be designed with a special material with higher Comparative Tracking Index (CTI), upgrading it from Material Group IIIa/IIIb to Group II or even Group I. In this case, if the board is manufactured with a generic type of solder mask, you definitely want to remove it across a critical insulation barrier. Conversely, special solder mask with high CTI also exists. But in practical, both cases are exceedingly rare.

[1] Including IEC 60950-1 (deprecated, office and computer equipment), IEC 62368-1 (current, office, computer, and AV equipment), IEC 61010-1 (lab equipment), and IEC 60664-1 (general insulation requirement).